# Neo4j/Cypher - find connected nodes that have more than 2 links

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a graph as follows (removed any labels or link directions for simplicity)

[image: Simple example graph]

I would like to start at node (c) and find only those nodes that have more than 2 adjacent edges, and the paths to them from (c).

In the example above, node (b) has 3 adjacent edges (b-a, b-c, b-g) and node (e) has 4 adjacent edges (e-d, e-f, e-h, e-h), so I would like to return the paths to just (b) and (e).

I also **do not** want to return the path to (a), (f), (h), (g) or (j) - I want to stop the traversal when the count is satisfied.

I've tried the following:

```
START n=node(c)
MATCH (n)-[r*]-(m)-[rx]-(o)
WITH m AS m, n AS n, r AS r, count(rx) as cnt
WHERE cnt > 2
RETURN n, r, m, cnt;
```

... but it returns paths to a, g, h, f and j in addition to b and e. It is also very costly for a big graph.

Very grateful for any help.

**EDIT:**

The example image I provided oversimplifies my data, so the initial suggestion doesn't work (see http://console.neo4j.org/?id=d6feml) so a new image example provided below.

**I want**: The paths to e an b only - as before.

**I don't want**: to return the path to h.

[image]

Thanks again neo4jers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting one, I've put it into Neo4j console using http://console.neo4j.org/r/qc7log.

The Cypher statement you're looking for is:

```
START n=node(2) // node c has node id = 2
MATCH p=(n)-[KNOWS*]-(m),(m)-[:KNOWS]-(x)
WITH p, count(x) AS count
WHERE count>2
RETURN p
```

The trick here is specify the path in the `MATCH` in two parts. The first part is then used for the aggregation using `WITH` and for the `RETURN`.

Comment: Amazing - thanks for the speedy response Stefan! Pleased to have contributed something (if only a question) to Neo4j console too.

Comment: OK, so it seems my example was too simple and the query didn't work for my dataset because I'd over simplified. The actual graph is much deeper, so your query doesn't quite perform as I'd hope it would. Here's a more accurate representation (now that I've learnt what neo4j console is): http://console.neo4j.org/?id=d6feml

Comment: you should probably limit the depth, instead of `[KNOWS*]` use e.g. [KNOWS*..10]` or whatever seems reasonable for your domain. This query could be implemented more efficiently using Java traversal API.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about a depth limit, but the nodes with >2 links could be at any depth. it is only the fact they have >2 links that differentiates them.
Agreed about traversal, that feels like the right solution - I'm using python neo4jrestclient and the traversal docs seem a bit thin.

Comment: how does the inverse approach perform? `MATCH n-[r] with n, count(r) as cnt WHERE cnt > 4 MATCH n--(n2{Id:2}) RETURN n`

Answer (score 0):

Based on Stefans suggestion to look at the traversal framework, I spent a while trying to figure it out in python (neo4j-rest-client). The following snippet now works:

```
# Retrieve the node at the start of the traveral
seed_node = gdb.nodes(node_id)

# Establish what the traversal should look like
simpleTraversalTemplate = traversals.TraversalDescription().relationships('adjacent')

# Set some un-chainable attributes - work breadth first and set max depth of traversal
simpleTraversalTemplate.breadthFirst()

# This is how far you think it will go before meeting a junction. 100 is high.
simpleTraversalTemplate.max_depth(100)

# Set up a prune evaluator. This by itself (without the filter evaluator)
# returns all traversals up to the point where the link count is > 2. This includes
# the traversals to the nodes before the >2 link_count node. 
simpleTraversalTemplate.prune(value={'body':"parseInt(position.endNode().getProperty('link_count')) > 2;",
                                     'language':'javascript'})

# So, a filter is used with the prune to only return those traversals where the end node link_count 
# is >2. With only this (ie without prune), the traversal would continue and just keep returning
# those nodes with link_count > 2. 
simpleTraversalTemplate.filter(value={'body':"parseInt(position.endNode().getProperty('link_count')) > 2;",
                                     'language':'javascript'})

# Now run the traverser based on the seed node
trav = simpleTraversalTemplate.traverse(seed_node)
```